# Confused with the SmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials Property

Tags: asp.net-mvc, smtpclient

In my MVC4 application, I'm using the `SmtpClient` to send out email via Gmail's `smtp.gmail.com` SMTP server.

I've configured my Web.Config file with the following settings:

```
<system.net>
 <mailSettings>
  <smtp deliveryMethod="Network">
   <network enableSsl="true" 
   defaultCredentials="false" 
   host="smtp.gmail.com" 
   port="587" 
   userName="xxMyUserNamexx@gmail.com" 
   password="xxMyPasswordxx" />
  </smtp>
 </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

The method that uses the SmtpClient and sends an email message looks like:

```
public void SendMail(string fromDisplayName, string fromEmailAddress, string toEmailAddress, string subject, string body)
{
    MailAddress from = new MailAddress(fromEmailAddress, fromDisplayName);
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress(toEmailAddress);
    MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(from, to);
    mailMessage.Body = body;
    mailMessage.Subject = subject;

    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
    //client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    client.Send(mailMessage);
}
```

The code above works as expected and is fine. What confuses me is the commented line `client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;` - If I were to uncomment that line, I'll receive an exception message that states:

> The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not
>   authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

What's more is, it doesn't matter if I set the `UseDefaultCredentials` property to `true` or `false`, I'll still receive the exception message. The only way for me to avoid the exception message is to remove the line altogether.

Is this behavior normal? Can you explain why I'm receiving the exception message?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> So why would me explicitly setting the property to false throw an exception?

The reason for this is because the setter for `UseDefaultCredentials` sets the `Credentials` property to null if you set it to false, or it sets it to the `CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials` property if set to true. The `DefaultNetworkCredentials` property is [defined by MSDN as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache.defaultnetworkcredentials.aspx):

> The credentials returned by DefaultNetworkCredentials represents the authentication credentials for the current security context in which the application is running. For a client-side application, these are usually the Windows credentials (user name, password, and domain) of the user running the application. For ASP.NET applications, the default network credentials are the user credentials of the logged-in user, or the user being impersonated.

When you set `UseDefaultCredentials` to true, it's using your IIS user, and I'm assuming that your IIS user does not have the same authentication credentials as your account for whatever SMTP server you're using. Setting `UseDefaultCredentials` to false null's out the credentials that are set. So either way you're getting that error.

Here's a look at the setter for `UseDefaultCredentials` using [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/):

```
set
{
    if (this.InCall)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            SR.GetString("SmtpInvalidOperationDuringSend"));
    }
    this.transport.Credentials = value 
        ? (ICredentialsByHost) CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials 
        : (ICredentialsByHost) null;
  }
```

Answer (score 17):

I was getting the same message and it was driving me crazy. After reading this thread I realized that the order mattered on setting my credentials. This worked:

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpSettings.Username, smtpSettings.Password);
```

While this generated the error you describe:

```
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpSettings.Username, smtpSettings.Password);
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

This is just an FYI to anybody else having the same problem.

Comment: The accepted answer by Dave Zych explains why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This option will set the client to use the default credentials of the currently logged in *user*

If you set it to true, then it will try to use the user's credentials.  If you set it to false, then it will use the values *explicitly* set for the Credentials property of the client, and if they aren't explicitly set, then it will try to connect anonymously as you are seeing.

Comment: That's what I initially thought, too. However, the client is not connecting anonymously - it's connecting with the credentials that are set in the Web.Config file (as noted in the OP). Not to mention, the MS spec says that [UseDefaultCredentials is false by default](http://goo.gl/fdx6U). So why would me explicitly setting the property to false throw an exception?

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can create SMTP Client with or without NetworkCredentials. I am using this code to send emails. We should use client.UseDefaultCredentials only when we are not passing credentials and going by default.

```
        private SmtpClient InitializeSMTPClient()
        {
            var client = new SmtpClient(_smtpServer, _smtpPort);

            client.UseDefaultCredentials = _useSMTPDefaultCredentials;

            if (_useSMTPDefaultCredentials)
                return client;

            var credentials = new NetworkCredential(_smtpUsername, _smtpPassword);
            client.Credentials = credentials;

            return client;
        }



        SMTPEmailResult SendSMTPEmail(List<string> to_email, List<string> ccEmails, string subject, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                using (var client = InitializeSMTPClient())
                {
                    var mail_message = GetMailMessage(to_email, ccEmails, subject, message);
                    log.Debug("Sending SMTP email.");
                    client.Send(mail_message);
                    log.Debug("SMTP email sent successfully.");
                    return SMTPEmailResult.SendSuccess;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex.Message, ex);
                return SMTPEmailResult.SendFailed;
            }
        }
```